# How to Implement Jquery Gantt Chart to display events in a year view in asp.net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a requirement in my project for displaying events in a year view in Gantt chart view.i have heard about Jquery Gantt Chart but i dont know how to implement it in my asp.net mvc application.please help

Comment: Please read the [help]

Answer (score 0):

you can use kendo Gantt Chart (jquery version)
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/index

Comment: i want the events to be displayed in a year View but as i see this does not support a year view. is this component free for use or a trial version? i am looking for a open source plugin just for displaying the events. i dont require any operations to be done on events.

Comment: Thanks for the information bhupesh.But i am looking for an open source plugin.

Comment: I dont think there is an open source Gantt available, Why dont you try to build your own Gantt then?